# Find every file in a directory and render them all using rdiscount

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rdiscount

I've got a directory called "posts" which is filled with .md files. Right now rdiscount renders only one file (one.md), then puts the product into a variable (@content). Because this is done issuing...

```
@content = markdown(:one)
```

...I'm really confused as to how to make ruby 1) find every file in the directory and 2) render everything using rdiscount. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @Simone Carletti's answer, in order to answer part 2 of your question:

```
@content = ""
Dir.glob("path/to/folder/*.md") do |file|
  @content << markdown(file)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to find and iterate all the Markdown files in the directory.

```
Dir.glob("path/to/folder/*.md") do |file|
  # do what you want with file
end
```